# Firefox 3.6 Anchor Link - Improper Functionality

Tags: html, firefox, jquery-mobile, firefox3.6

I have a jQuery Mobile Site that is using anchor tagging for navigation. The site has a URL like http://domain_name_here.com/smartphone/home.jsp. When I navigate to a page within the site, for example a product, a link would take you to #product?id=XXX and everything works fine.

However, in Firefox 3.6, I have a link that takes users to #home `<a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>` but when a user clicks on it, they are taken to "#/smartphone/home.jsp" instead of the expected "#home." The URL in Firefox 3.6 looks like "http://domain_name_here.com/smartphone/#smartphone/home.jsp" after clicking on the link defined above. This problem seems unique to Firefox 3.6 and it works perfectly fine on all other browsers.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem, and if so, is there anyway to fix it. The point of using the hash tag is to not reload the page, so a solution that would require the page being loaded again is not valid.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your problem. Firefox 3.6 isn't a mobile browser, and the only supported version is FF mobile 10 Beta. Supported Browsers for jquery mobile > [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/about/platforms.html)

Comment: @jhilgert00 I presume he means that he tests his mobile website on a desktop computer using a desktop browser, and that the behaviour he describes shouldn't happen. But without an actual link, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Yeah, testing mobile site on FF 3.6. Also found the same problem using few older droids using Opera Mini. Can't give link since site is not public yet.

Comment: setting ahref="home.jsp#home" seems to be a solution for now, but the fact that clicking on a link with href="#home" isn't taking me to "#home" is concerning.

Comment: I know FF3.6 isn't officially supported by jquerymobile, and neither is opera mini (B-grade).